# Spring Security sessionID as token configuration

Tags: spring, rest, session, spring-security, spring-session

I am implementing a login process using Spring Security + Spring session to build login functionality for a REST like backend service that needs to create/mantain a session.

I am not sure if I am approaching the solution the right way since I am using a custom endpoint to create the session manually.  Maybe the session creation needs to be done in the Authorization method itself? Or maybe there is a way to have spring create the session after some request validations in the backend? I am using a custom filter and provider for this.

Also with my current configuration, I am having an issue since the backend API is creating a new session with every request, even when it should return 401.

The requirements of this solution is as follows:

1. The clients will login to a third party authentication/authorization provider.  Once validated, the provider will issue an access token.
2. The API must validate the client's access token with the third party provider.  Once validated, the API must create a session and return a new token (or sessionID) to the clients.
3. Future calls to the API should include the token (or sessionID) in the header/cookie so the API gets the session of the client.

**The big question here is:**  Is there a common approach to follow for using token based authentication linked to a user session?  If so, what if I need to do custom validations before having spring session create the session, and also add custom attributes to this session?

My code is located here: https://github.com/munilvc/api-session/tree/master/src/main/java/com/munilvc/poc/security

For instance, some sample executions:

1) Execute custom login:

```
$ curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/app-api/login/createsession -v
> POST /app-api/login/createsession HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.49.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200
< x-auth-token: 15a06ce8-5b34-401a-a05f-a0d933926245
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Tue, 29 Aug 2017 01:28:24 GMT
<
171{"username":"username1"}
```

2) Call another endpoint with provided x-auth-token:

NOTE the x-auth-token is refreshed in the response. (means a new session is created - This is what we want to avoid, this also happens when response is 401)

```
$ curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/app-api/accounts/2 -H "x-auth-token:15a06ce8-5b34-401a-a05f-a0d933926245" -v
> GET /app-api/accounts/2 HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.49.1
> Accept: */*
> x-auth-token:15a06ce8-5b34-401a-a05f-a0d933926245
>
< HTTP/1.1 200
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< x-auth-token: 42a5db80-e5e1-4127-bd85-e468af4a8fb2
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Tue, 29 Aug 2017 01:29:08 GMT
<
870{"id":3,"name":"Account 3"}
```

PS: I am not sure if I am allowed to provide a link to the code in stack overflow.  If not, I can paste the code here as well.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements, OpenID Connect can be used to authenticate the end-user and authorize a client which will then receive an `AccessToken`. Then the `AccessToken` may be used to call the back-end API's (Resource Servers).

Take a look at this [sample/guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/samples/boot/oauth2login) on how to setup login within Spring Security 5 against an external OAuth 2.0 or OpenID Connect provider. This will meet your requirement for logging into the application using an external provider and creating a secure session within Spring Security.

Now that you are logged in to the application and the client has an `AccessToken`, the client can use that `AccessToken` in the request (Authorization Header) to call the back-end API's (Resource Servers). The Resource Server should be setup to validate the incoming `AccessToken`. Take a look at this [sample](https://github.com/jgrandja/spring-security-oauth-sample) ([master](https://github.com/jgrandja/spring-security-oauth-sample/tree/master) and [jwt-support](https://github.com/jgrandja/spring-security-oauth-sample/tree/jwt-support) branches) on how to configure a Resource Server.

I would strongly recommend becoming more familiar with [OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) and [OpenID Connect Core 1.0](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html).

Good luck!